# Const functor returning reference of T is prohibiting assignment

Tags: c++

Why is it not possible to assign a value to a reference returned by a const functor?

```
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
class Test {
public:
  T & operator()(size_t index) const {
    return A[index];
  }

private:
  std::vector<T> A{1,2,3};
};

int main() {
  const Test<double> test1;
  const Test<double> test2;
  Test<double> test;

  test(0) = test1(0) + test2(1);
}
```

I get the compiling errors below but I don't understand why the const of the functor is prohibiting the assignment because the functor itself isn't changing its object.

```
main.cpp:7:12: error: binding value of type 'const
      __gnu_cxx::__alloc_traits<std::allocator<double> >::value_type' (aka 'const double') to
      reference to type 'double' drops 'const' qualifier
    return A[index];
           ^~~~~~~~
main.cpp:19:7: note: in instantiation of member function 'Test<double>::operator()' requested
      here
  test(0) = test1(0) + test2(1);
      ^
```

If the functor wouldn't be const I would get a compiling error because of the `const Test<double> test1`, but this is clear to me.
How can I get the code above to be running? I need to use the functor to assign values from const objects.

Comment: you cannot modify a `const` object. What are you trying to achieve? "How can I get the code above to be running?" you cant.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`this` in the context of that method is a `Test<double> const *` which means that `this->A` is implicitly `const`. Therefore, `A[index]` has type `double const &` which cannot be converted to `T &` (which is `double &`).

To put it another way, instance members of a `const` object are themselves `const` (unless they are declared `mutable`).

The correct solution is to have two `operator()` implementations, one `const` and one not:

```
T       & operator()(size_t index)       { return A[index]; }
T const & operator()(size_t index) const { return A[index]; }
```

The former will be called on non-const instances and *does* allow assignment; the latter will be called on const instances and *does not* allow assignment.

([Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c20de1fb658d59b2))

Comment: Thanks, that was very clarifying to me

Answer (score 4):

As others have stated, what you have won't work because `this` is `const` inside of a method marked as `const`, so `A` will also be `const`, and `A[index]` will return a `const` reference, and you can't assign a `const` reference to a non-`const` reference, like you are attempting to do.

In this situation, you need two `operator()` implementations, one that is `const` and one that is not.  The `+` operator can use the `const` version to read values from the `const` objects, and the `=` operator can use the non-`const` version to write the result to the non-`const` object:

```cpp
template<typename T>
class Test {
public:
  const T& operator()(size_t index) const {
    return A[index];
  }
  /* or:
  T operator()(size_t index) const {
    return A[index];
  }
  */

  T& operator()(size_t index) {
    return A[index];
  }

private:
  std::vector<T> A{1,2,3};
};

int main() {
  const Test<double> test1;
  const Test<double> test2;
  Test<double> test;

  test(0) = test1(0) + test2(1);
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/0WBqAu)

Answer (score 2):

When you have an object of type `const Test<...>`, the member variable `A` is also a `const` object.

That prevents `A[0]` from be assigned to. `A[0]` evaluates to a `const&`, not a non-`const&`.